# id3 tags editing with vim

Tags: vim, vi, id3, id3-tag, id3v2

Is there any way I can use gvim or vim to edit id3 tags on already ripped .flac files? Also, maybe somebody know a way to integrate gvim tag editing with rubyripper? Also, I'd like edit id3 tags on flac **and** mp3 files.

A command line tool which could be somehow integrated with vim would also do the job.

Thanks in advance,

Ignas

Comment: Vim is generally a text editor for text (and alike) files. And although, somewhere out there probably something exists that enables it to edit id3 tags, you would have a *much more pleasant experience doing it with a dedicated editor for such purpose*.

Answer (score 2):

Vim is probably not the tool you should be using this for. A dedicated command-line utility is a much better option.

Some options:

- [id3v2](http://id3v2.sourceforge.net/)
- [mp3info](http://ibiblio.org/mp3info/)
- [id3ed](http://freecode.com/projects/id3ed)

Comment: Honestly, I really would like to do this with vim.  `vorbistagedit` does pretty much exactly what I want, but unfortunately only works on vorbis files (e.g. `.ogg`).

Comment: `vorbistagedit` has been extended to also support mp3 files. The program is called tagedit: https://github.com/goodevilgenius/tagedit

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool for that called [taggie](https://github.com/ravicious/taggie/). From the rationale section:

> From time to time I download a release from Bandcamp where the tags are messed up, especially when we're talking about compilation albums from various artists. MusicBrainz Picard doesn't help there if the release is fresh.
>
> It's easy enough to modify the album or album artist tags in iTunes because it's setting one value for all tracks. However, sometimes there's more you need to change: the "title" tag is in the format "[title] - [artist]" or each title contains some junk that you want to remove.